# Binomal dist. statistics coin flip question

Tags: statistics

I have the following consolidation question as per a worksheet.

`An experiment consists of flipping a fair coin 8 times and counting the number of
tails. Find the probability of seeing exactly 6 or 7 tails`

I assumed out of the three probabilities we were learning Binomial would be the best one to tackle this. My only issue is what do I use for the $P(X=x)$ part of the formula. Since it's $6$ or $7$ heads to I calculate $6$ using $P(X=6)$ and then calculate $7$ $P(X=7)$ both independently rather then in the same formula? I'm not quite sure how to get both of them in the one formula and I don't think you can.

I have currently tried solving for each probability of $6$ and probability of $7$…And have two values.

I did the following for $6$:

$$
\frac{8!}{6!(8-6)!}0.5^6(1-0.5)^2` = 0.109375
$$

and for $7$:

$$
\frac{8!}{7!(8-7)!}0.5^7(1-0.5)^1 = 0.03125
$$

So my question is, what now, have I answered the question or do I need to add these probabilities together or something?

Comment: You calculate the probability that $X=6$, and separately the prob. it is $7$, and add. Make sure you look up the exact formula.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yeah thanks, left a bit off fixed up my answer incase someone else looks at it and needs help or something, cheers

Comment: You are welcome. To be formal, $X=6$ and $X=7$ are *disjoint* events. So to find the probability that $X=6$ **or** $X=7$, one adds the probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mass function for the binomial is

$$
{n \choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}
$$

You should especially make note of the $p^x$ part -- you are leaving out the $x$ in the exponent of $p$.

Your way of doing $Pr(X=6\text{ or } X=7)$ is the easiest way of doing it. So have a look at the probability mass function again and you should be fine.

Comment: Yeah i just realised i forgot the x on p in the middle was wondering how there was a probability of over 1 haha